# CA Network Flow Analysis - Clear out old statistics

Tags: sflow

Does anyone know how to clear out all the data in CA NFA ?
I'm currently testing out some sFlow monitoring but want to remove all the previously gathered data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this by stopping the Harvester service on the NFA server, and deleting the routers from NFA, then waiting a few days before adding the routers back in.